# How do I use the Commerce Fulfilment module drag and drop?

Tags: commerce

I have created orders and I'm using the [Flat Rate Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_flat_rate) module. Everything is working except the [Fulfillment](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fulfillment) module. When I select the Fulfillment TAB I get an error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line
>   335 of...

I wonder what I'm doing wrong?
Anybody get this module to work? I'd love to hear about a success and maybe get some help. Thanks